# Is there such thing as an empty date in C#

Tags: oracle, variables, c#-4.0, nullable

I am trying to input a date into an Oracle database.  Sometime this value will be null.  So in the function that I am writing I need a way to be able to pass in this null value.  I am passing in this date as a parameter to  stored proc.  This parameter can be null.  I am using the Oracle.DataAccess dll to get this thing to work.  If it is indeed null, I am thinking of just throwing in a null variable.  Do you think that would work???  Here is how I currently am  setting up this scenario...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ACTIVE_DATEIn", DateTime.Parse(ActiveDate));
conn.Open();
outcome = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Active Date is the possible null variable that I am going to pass in.  Obviously you can't Convert a null value into a date Time.  What would you guys suggest doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `DateTime` is a `struct`, it cannot contain a `null` value.

Some people use `DateTime.MinValue` to store a null value.  A better approach would perhaps be to make `ActiveDate` a `DateTime?` instead.

**Update:**

You can also try something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ACTIVE_DATEIn", (ActiveDate == null ? OracleDate.Null : OracleDate.Parse(ActiveDate)));
```

Comment: No good.  I keep getting the same exception.  But I do indeed like this answer.

Comment: If the value is null, try passing in `OracleDate.Null` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can make `DateTime` implement INullable by placing a `?` after the type.

```
DateTime? date;
```

Which is ofcourse equivalent to

```
Nullable<DateTime> date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.MinValue` instead of null, or make your DateTime object nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `DBNull.Value` in the case that your `ActiveDate` represents a null.